# how to traverse a boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, iterator, boost-multi-array

I have been looking into the boost::multi_array library in search of an iterator that allows you to traverse *the whole* multi_array in a single for loop.

I don't think there is any such iterator in that library. (The iterators that are found there let you traverse a single dimension of the multi_array)

Am I wrong?
If not, is there any library that defines such an iterator?

Entering into details, I'd like to write something like:

```
boost::multi_array< double, 3 > ma(boost::extents[3][4][2]);  

for( my_iterator it = ma.begin(); it != ma.end(); ++it )  
{  
    // do something  
    // here *it has element type (in this case double)  
}
```

and obtain a loop that repeats 3x4x2 times

Answer (score 11):

You can use an implementation of `std::for_each` from `<algorithm>` to access each individual element. There is an example in the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/example/foreach_test.cpp)

Alternatively, you can use `array::origin()` and `array::num_elements()` as follows:

```
boost::multi_array< double, 3 > ma(boost::extents[3][4][2]);  

for(auto i = ma.origin(); i < (ma.origin() + ma.num_elements()); ++i)  
{  
    // do something with i
}
```

Comment: I believe you want ma.data() rather than ma.origin() for the concrete boost::multi_array and boost::multi_array_ref classes.  origin() will do the wrong thing for non-zero index_bases() while data() will work correctly.

Comment: @Maarten That example in the link shows boost::for_each (not std::for_each), which expects a range iterator, right (versus a start and end in the std version)? multi_array didn't seem to provide either of these (.begin/end() or the automatic range iterator) in my experiment.