# Traversing indices of contiguous 3d grid without nested loops

Tags: c++, c++11, grid, traversal

I would like cell indices of a contiguous (box-shaped) area area in a 3d grid, i.e. a 3d set `{iMin…iMax}×{jMin…jMax}×{kMin…kMax}`. The naive approach would be:

```
for(int i=iMin; i<=iMax; i++){
  for(int j=jMin; j<=jMax; j++){
    for(int k=kMin; k<=kMax; k++){
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a less verbose way to do that, without nested loops?

(I am in c++11 and have a `Vector3i` class for coordinates. I can use any boost library, also.)

Comment: As contiguity cannot not be guaranteed in full generality; I doubt it. The three loops will probably be faster (and certainly clearer) than one iterating variable and an elaborate mapping algorithm from that to the coordinates.

Comment: If you have control over the `Vector3i` class, you could overload `operator[]` if you wanted. However, what's the problem with nested loops? That way, it's very clear to every reader of your code what you're doing.

Comment: `Vector3i` is from [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org); it already defines `operator[]`. Nested loops take three lines and it is easy to mistype something.

Comment: @Bathsheba: the range IS contiguous, I am pretty sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be wrapping you 3 fors into algorithm for_each_3d and pass it a lambda, but it will only work for 3d and accessing neighboring elements would be a pain. Or you can use boost_mutli array and loop similar to this:
[how to traverse a boost::multi_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572464/how-to-traverse-a-boostmulti-array)
Note, that multi_array is an array and cannot be resized after construction

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single loop you can go for something like this:

```
int main()
{
  size_t const N=8, M=N*N*N;
  size_t x(0), y(0), z(0);
  for (size_t i=0; i<M; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << std::endl;
    ++z;
    if (z == N)
    {
      z=0;
      ++y;
      if (y == N)
      {
        y=0;
        ++x;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But don't say I told you it looks nice! ;)

Comment: WOW, that's really ugly ;)